# I need to repeat control-c to copy text in gedit, libreoffice writer, etc

Tags: libreoffice, gedit, text-editor, copy-and-paste

When I copy a text, either a single word or a novel-length text, in text-editors like LibreOffice writer or Gedit, sometimes I need to hit control-c again because it doesn't work and it will paste the previously copied text, if there is any, or nothing will be pasted at all.

As a story writer, journalist and book editor, I need to use that shortcut thousands of times a day, and it is very annoying to paste and see you need to undo a cut, go back pages and find the original text you want, and copy it again.
One solution is to get used to hitting control-c several times every time I want to copy, but there must be smarter solutions I guess.

I mostly write, read, and edit in Persian, but I think the problem cannot be the language, though I am not sure by the way. I am using Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: looks like the bug here: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1852183

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate which version of Ubuntu you are using. If 19.10 then the bug link you posted seems valid.

Comment: For sure it must be 19.10 you are using. I confirm this issue.

Comment: this bug is still there after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04, and also there after a fresh install